# Replace duplicates Items from a string using Regex

Tags: regex

I have a string which looks something like this

```
xyz 123;abc;xyz 123;efg;
```

I want to remove the duplicates and keep only one occurrence in the string. I want the output to be like this

```
xyz 123;abc;efg;
```

I tried using `(?<=;|^)([^;]*);(\1)+(?=;|$)` but couldn't figure out how to remove one of the duplicates. Any suggestions ?

Comment: [`(([^;]*;).*)(\2)`](https://regex101.com/r/8ChNZw/2/)

Comment: Since you want to keep the first occurrence, you might have trouble using a single regex for this. Split, keep the first occurrences only, join back. Unless you are using .NET or Python `regex` module that support unknown-width lookbehind.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't think it's JS since OP is using a lookbehind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in a comma-separated list with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046492/removing-duplicates-in-a-comma-separated-list-with-a-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your suggestions. Finally i got this working with this regex

```
(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)(?=,|$)
```

Comment: Here the separator is a comma, and you need to remove the change the occurrences of `\\\` in the regex to a single slash.

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

Since you didn't specify a language, I'll assume the tokens in your original regex are all working in whatever language you're using.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/8ChNZw/3/)

```
(([^;]*;).*)\2
```

Replace with `\1`

---

### Explanation

- `(([^;]*;).*)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `([^;]*;)` Capture the following into capture group 2
     -`[^;]*` Match any character except the semi-colon character `;` any number of times

    - `;` Match the semi-colon character literally
- `\2` Matches the same text as most recently matched by the second capture group

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above regex doesn't replace duplicate occurrence if it's more than 2. In  my case the duplicate occurrence can be many. By the way I'm using perl based regex.

Comment: Well in that case you should just split the string on `;` and remove duplicates.

Comment: I got close with a regex `?<=;|^)([^;]*)(?=.*\b\1\b)` but it doesn't work if the string is something like this:

Comment: I got close with a regex `?<=;|^)([^;]*)(?=.*\b\1\b)` but it doesn't work if the string is something like this:
`sheet2.xml;sheet2.ppt;note pad.docx;` 

The output looks like 
`.xml;sheet2.ppt;note pad.docx;`

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The below is for java.
For duplicate words(consequent/random) you can use the regex string as 
\b(\w+)\b(?=.*?\b\1\b

For duplicate characters(consequent/random) in a string you can use 
(.)(?=.*?\1)